# handling onchange with 2 submit buttons jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a list pulled from a database that currently uses 2 submit buttons.  one to refresh the page with a different set of data and the other to update the page.

the code is basically...

```
// this is a little bit pseudo so dont worry about spelling mistakes...

<?php

if($_POST['update']) {
    // update database
}

if($_POST['filter']) {
    // show different data
}

?>
<form type="post">

<button type="submit" name= "update" value="update">Update</button>
<select name="selectitem">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<button type='submit' name='filter' value='filter'>Filter</button>
</form>
```

This works fine but I was thinking it would be better to have the select element do the refresh when changed using onChange but how do i get it to submit the right button (in this case the filter button).  I am using jquery so suggestions using that would be fine too.

the form posts back to the same page so it can refresh or update the data based on the select element.

I guess i want to get rid of the filter button but perform its specific action onchange of the select element.

hope you can help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set an event handler on the select element that will trigger a click to the button.
Like this:

```
$('select[name="selectitem"]').change(function(e) {
   $('button[name="filter"]').click();
});
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: thanks. Will try that when I get home. Thank you very much for answering.

Comment: Worked a charm. Thanks